# How to parse all correct file types using Roslyn

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

So i want to load all the C# files in my project so i can parse them using Roslyn.

I want to do something like this:

```
foreach(var file in project.Files.OfType<ROSLYN FILE TYPE HERE>())
{
... do something...
}
```

How can i achieve this. Or is it even possible?

Comment: What is "project" in this context? A variable holding...what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the C# files out of the project using the [`Documents`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/update-1/src/Workspaces/Core/Portable/Workspace/Solution/Project.cs#L268) property on the project.
The extension method below gets all the C# files from a given project.

```cs
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

static public IEnumerable<Document> CSFiles(this Project project) =>
    "C#" == project?.Language ?
    project?.Documents?.Where(Document => Document.SupportsSemanticModel) : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it like this :

```
project.Files.Where(file=>Path.GetExtension(file.FilePath)=="cs")
```

but i do not like it. Anyone has better ideas?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer...beats me what type "project" is, or where you are getting it from, etc.